# Why my array is NaN and I can not get value from Firebase Database?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Now I am trying to get some values from Firebase Database in React Native Project but I couldn't.

My JSON tree in Database is like below.

```
MyApp
  ┗restaurant
        ┗restaurant0
        ┃   ┗name: xxx
        ┃   ┗address: yyy
```

And this is my code.

```
  componentWillMount() {
const databaseGenreRestaurantRef = firebase.database().ref('restaurant/');
databaseGenreRestaurantRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach(() => {
    let num = 0;
    let restaurantNum = 'restaurant' + num;
    const restaurantList = [];
    restaurantList.push(snapshot.val().restaurant + num.name);
    this.setState({ restaurantList });
    num ++;
    console.log(restaurantList);
  });
});
```

}

I would like to get each value of array and push these value to state but 
I got "NaN" through console.log.

Why I got NaN and How to soleve this problem?

Comment: you'll have to decide if num should be a `number` (see: num ++) or an `object` (see: num.name)

Comment: Thank you for your comment but sorry I cannot understand what you mean.
Could you give me some example code or more details?

Comment: your variable `num` starts as a number (0), then you acces num.name (there is no `.name` on a number), the you increment(++) num - so what *should* num be? Because the answer to your problem depends on what you intended `num` to be.

Comment: I see. That is my mistake. Which mean I wanted to use ('restaurant' + num).name.